# What is the correct way to use python Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

The document of Requests give some code like this

```
s = requests.Session()

s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/123456789')
r = s.get("http://httpbin.org/cookies")
```

If I want to use the connection-pooling feature of request.Session, Do I need to instantiate a new Session every time  I send a request?, If I do not need a new session, how can I check whether the old seesion is valid now?

Comment: Every time I send a request, If I do not need a new session, how can I check whether the old seesion is valid now?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use connection pooling you do *not* want to create a new session. Connection-pooling is managed by the `Session` object, and you should pass all your requests through it.

In general, if you are using Requests to perform more than two or three HTTP requests in your program you should create a single `Session` object and run all your requests through it. This will give you all the nice things Requests has to offer, like cookie persistence and connection pooling.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've looked at the documentation and... I think it automatically keeps your session alive for you.

Let me know if you have any problems with dying sessions, but assume that Requests will deal with that for you. I may have misinterpreted the docs, but I don't think you need to worry about it.

From the documentation:

> Keep-Alive
>
> Excellent news — thanks to urllib3, keep-alive is 100% automatic within a session!
>   Any requests that you make within a session will automatically reuse the appropriate 
>   connection!
>
> Note that connections are only released back to the pool for reuse once all body data 
>   has been read; be sure to either set stream to False or read the content property of 
>   the Response object.